# Read One row from Big XMl File

Tags: xml

I have too big xml file so insted of use dataset to load it i would like to see an example about how can i read one specific record from my big xml file insted of load all file in memory.

Comment: What computer language?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx). And [here's an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056.aspx).